# Access specific elements of a list in Python

Tags: python, list

In Python, say we have

```
L = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
```

and I want to store the elements at indices 1,3,5,6 in another list. In a program like GAP, this is a one-liner:

```
>>> New_L = L{[1,3,5,6]};

['b', 'd', 'f', 'g']
```

I've always wondered: is there something like this in Python? Or is this only done roughly as follows:

```
New_L = []
for i in [1,3,5,6]:
    New_L.append(L[i])
```

Comment: Numpy might have something for their arrays. Otherwise, if you want it succinct, you could just wrap that in a function.

Comment: as long as you have the indices stored in another container you can do some list comprehension `New_L = [L[ind] for ind in inds]`

Comment: Yeah I usually have a function defined for. I like the list comprehension suggestion -that works well thanks!

Comment: It is possible in Python to take a slice of a list e.g. `New_L = L[start:stop:step]`

So, in your case it is `New_L = L[1::2]`

Comment: As @Carcigenicate mentioned, [its possible with Numpy arrays as described here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indexing-in-numpy/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be written as list comprehension in one line:

```
New_L = [L[i] for i in [1,3,5,6]]
```